# What is the record limit of MySQL extended insert statement?

Tags: mysql, insert, limit

What is the record limit (n) of MySQL extended insert statement?

```
INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES (1),(2),(n)
```

What happens when the limit exceeds? Will only overflow rows left out or the whole statement failed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't believe there's any hard limit on the number of rows inserted. There is a limit on the maximum size of a MySQL query in general, though; statements longer than the setting of `max_allowed_packet` will be rejected by the server. (They won't run at all.)

[MySQL 5.5.6](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) changed the default value of `max_allowed_packet` from 1 MB to 4 MB. That's still quite a bit. :)